# Encoding is incorrect when page is run from POST request

Tags: php, python, utf-8, character-encoding

I am uploading a csv file to my webpage from a python script.

Python Code:

```
url = 'http://MYURL'
files = {'file': ('report.csv', report)} // report is my csv file
resp = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

PHP Code:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); // Having this made no difference to output
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
$keys = array_shift($csv);
foreach ($csv as $index => $values) { // For every row in csv
    $result = array_combine($keys, $values);
    $result = array_map('utf8_encode', $result); // Add UTF-8 encoding
    var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($result['Name']));
    var_dump($result['Name']);
}
```

Whether I run the PHP Script directly by uploading file myself or using the Python script to upload the file, `mb_detect_encoding()` returns 'UTF-8'.

However, running the PHP Script directly has `$result['Name']` return `ü` (correct). Running from Python script returns `Ã¼` (inaccurate).

The .csv file being uploaded is exactly the same and encoded as ISO-8859-1. Why does running from Python script cause the encoding to not be correct?

Edit:

Here are the results of `hexdump -C csvfile.csv`

```
00000000  22 58 58 58 58 20 fc 62  65 72 22    |"XXXX .ber"|
0000000b
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `file` as you are, instead I would use `fgetcsv` that way you can reduce the memory usage to a single line as you read the file instead of loading the entire file into memory.  - just a thought.

Comment: `utf8_encode` this is wrong, whatever you wanted to do it doesn't do that.

Comment: @Dharman if I don't do it, the character becomes �

Comment: Show output from `hexdump -C yourfile.csv`. Obviously, just enough data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: or if you don't know how to hex dump at least tell us what encoding is your file using?

Comment: Added output from hexdump. File is encoded as ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @miken32: ü is `fc` in hex and is in my hexdump output

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce with Python 3.6 and [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) requests module; printing `resp.text` shows me exactly the same thing as the browser.